# Solve for the inverse CDF of the Kumaraswamy distribution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

tl;dr how would you solve for $x$, where $u = 1 - (1 - x^a)^b$?

Slightly longer version: This is just an algebra question, I'm mainly having trouble expanding with the exponents, I'm not sure how to do this correctly!

Irrelevant background: The CDF of the Kumaraswamy distribution, $F_X(x)$, is $1 - (1 - x^a)^b$, where $0 < x < 1$ and $a > 0, b > 0$. I'm trying to use the inverse transform method to generate a set of random values from the distribution. To do this, I need to find the inverse CDF, $F_X^{-1}$. We can generate random values from a uniform distribution, and set those equal to the inverse CDF. Then solve to generate random values from the Kumaraswamy distribution. $a$ and $b$ are just constants, and $u$ is a random value from the uniform distribution.

$$u = 1 - (1 - x^a)^b$$

My algebra is terrible, so my best guess is that

$$
u = 1 - (1 - x^a)^b \\
u = 1 - 1^b - x^{ab}\\
x^{ab} = 1 - 1^b - u \\
x = (1 - 1^b - u)^{1/ab}
$$

I suspect that's not right and that I've messed up the first step, but am having trouble finding exactly how to solve this sort of equation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is wrong because $(1-x^{a})^{b}$ is not equal to $1^{b}-x^{ab}$.

$1-u=(1-x^{a})^{b}$.

$(1-u)^{1/b}=1-x^{a}$.

$1-(1-u)^{1/b}=x^{a}$

$x=(1-(1-u)^{1/b})^{1/a}$.